# prove that maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by a prime number

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I am trying to prove $(a)$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$,  if and only if $a$ is prime number.

Now I wrote:
assume $a \in\mathbb{Z}$, while it's not prime number
we can write as $a=xy$, for some integers $x$ and $y$.
then $(a)\subset (x)$ and $(a)\subset (y)$

while if $(a)$ is maximal ideal, it's not exist $(k)$ such that $(a)\subset (k)\subset\mathbb{Z}$.
so $(a)$ cannot be maximal ideal.
we can say by contradictory if $a$ is prime, $(a)$ is maximal ideal.

is this correct? 
and how to prove the other way.

Comment: This generalizes: if $R$ is a PID then an ideal $(a) \subseteq R$ is maximal iff $a$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: can you prove that every ideal is generated by one element in $\mathbb{Z}$? Can you prove that if $ \langle x\rangle \subset \langle y \rangle $, then $ x $ is divisible by $ y$?

And yes, your approach is correct

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to prove $\langle a \rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$,  if and only if $a$ is prime number.
>
> ... assume $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, ... [if] it's not [a] prime number we can write as $a = xy$, for some integers $x$ and $y$. Then $\langle a \rangle \subset \langle x \rangle$ and $\langle a \rangle \subset \langle y \rangle$.

Looks good so far.

> while if $\langle a \rangle$ is maximal ideal, [there does not] exist $\langle k \rangle$ such that $\langle a \rangle \subset \langle k \rangle\subset \mathbb{Z}$.

I think the unspoken assumption here is that $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, so that $\langle k \rangle$ is a principal ideal. Then I think you either need to prove that all ideals in $\mathbb Z$ are principal, or refer to a proof of that fact by someone else.

Because without that result, how can you be sure $\langle a \rangle \subset \langle a, k \rangle \subset \mathbb{Z}$ is not a possibility?

Rewrite the previous set comparison as $\langle a \rangle \subseteq \langle a, k \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. If $\gcd(a, k) = 1$, then $\langle a, k \rangle = \mathbb{Z}$. But if $\gcd(a, k) = |a|$, then $\langle a \rangle = \langle a, k \rangle$.

But that's just me talking without proving all ideals are principal in this domain.

> so $\langle a \rangle$ cannot be maximal ideal.
>   we can say by contradictory if $a$ is prime, $\langle a \rangle$ is maximal ideal.
>
> is this correct? 
>   and how to prove the other way.

With the missing assumption filled in, then yes, this is correct. I'm not sure what you mean by "the other way."