# Show that each subgroup generated by prime integer is maximal in $(\Bbb Z, +)$.

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers

> Show that each subgroup generated by prime integer is maximal in $(\Bbb Z, +)$.

Here I know that we can prove maximal by showing its quotient group is simple.

But how can I approach "each subgroup generated by prime integer"?

Comment: Check this out https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2811741

Comment: A subgroup generated by an element $g$ of a group $G$ is the subgroup given by all multiples of $g$ and its inverse, all with respect to the operation on $G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you work out as Shaun mentioned in the comment, you will see that the subgroup generated by the prime number  $p $, $$\langle p \rangle=\{\ldots,-2p,-p,0,p,\ldots\}=p\Bbb Z.$$

In fact,since $\Bbb Z$ is cyclic, every subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ is cyclic,i.e.,every subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ is of the form $n\Bbb Z$ for some  $n\in \Bbb Z$.

To show $p\Bbb Z$ is maximal in $\Bbb Z$, you can use the fact that$$\frac{\Bbb Z}{p\Bbb Z}\cong \Bbb Z_p. $$

Comment: I have understood.Thanks